# How to run "listening" commands in java runtime

Tags: java

I need to run `iperf3` server side using java on `API` call. I found this way to run commands in java but I don't know how to terminate it later

```
public String requestExecute(String query, HttpServletRequest request) throws SocketException {
        String s; 
        String toDisplay = ""; 
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(query);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                toDisplay += s + "\n";
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exit: " + toDisplay);
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
   
        return toDisplay;
    }
```

How do you terminate it, maybe I just set time limit?

Comment: What does the documentation of `waitFor` say about its parameters?

Comment: Should have checked before my bad

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to terminate it by checking if `s` string contains a certain charset. My current function:

```
public String requestExecute(String query, HttpServletRequest request,String username) throws SocketException {
        String s;
        String toDisplay = "";
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(query);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                toDisplay += s + "\n";
                if (s.contains("receiver")) {
                    p.destroy();
                    break;
                }
            }
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return toDisplay;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).